# How do I reference an object from another GUI that is running in a seperate java file?

Tags: java, swing, reference, external

This maybe a basic question, but I am new to programming.

I have two GUI forms running at one time, `UploadGui` and `UploadPurchaseData`. I need the `UploadPurchaseData` form to call a value from a text field in `UploadGui` called `txtFirstName`. `UploadGui` and `UploadPurchaseData` are separate jFrame files, but they are in the same project.

Here is the code I have so far for the `UploadPurchaseData` button to upload the inserted values into the database

```
private void cmdAddPurchaseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    String ps = comboPurchaseStage.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int pv = Integer.parseInt(txtPropertyValue.getText());
    int la = Integer.parseInt(txtLoanAmount.getText());
    //here is where is need the code to reference txtFirstName from UploadGUI
}
```

Here is the code that opens `UploadPurchaseData` at the same time as `UploadGUI` is open:

```
private void comboLTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String lt = comboLT.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (lt == "Purchase")
    {
    UploadPurchaseData anotherFrame = new  UploadPurchaseData();
    anotherFrame.pack();
    anotherFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Pass a reference of UploadGui (or the 'text field' `txtFirstName`) to the `UploadPurchaseData` object.

Comment: How do I pass that reference? As in that would be the code for that?

Comment: There are many ways: in the constructor, via a setter method...without any context (eg `code`) we can only provide textual suggestions (rather than code suggestions )

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)